# Protobuf declaring i'm missing required fields when i'm clearly not

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a lightweight server-client system using protobuf as the serialization system. I'm having problems with protobufs complaining about missing required fields but 1) the fields are clearly there in the data stream and 2) the error message doesn't identify the missing field(s).

first a bit of code:

```
myMessages::DataRequest cData;  // this is declared outside of the function in the global
                                // so it can be reused each time to avoid unnecessary
                                // memory allocation. Per the documentation in protobufs
.
.
.

bool processStream(u_int8_t *pStream, u_int32_t dwLength)
{
try
{
    if (!cData.ParseFromArray(pStream, dwLength))
    {
        printf("Failed to parse data stream\n");
        hexdump(pStream, dwLength);
        return false;
    }
}
catch(exception e)
{
    printf("Exception in ParseFromArray: %s", e.what());
    hexdump(pStream, dwLength);
    return false;
}
```

this is the code where i'm taking the full data stream and trying to get protobufs to decode it. Most of the time this works fine. But every so many iterations through this code I get this error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "myMessages.DataRequest" because it is missing required fields:
```

As a result of the failure, my code spits out this showing me the buffer that was given to the protobuf parser:

```
Failed to parse data stream
000000: 08 86 ad 80 a5 f0 e7 aa e7 01 12 06 64 37 32 36  ............d726
000010: 31 37
```

The DataRequest .proto is pretty simple...

```
message DataRequest {
required uint64 timeStamp = 1;
required string strid= 2;
optional bool checkin= 3;

// event messages
repeated internalMessage1 iEvents = 5;
repeated internalMessage2 oEvents = 6;
repeated internalMessage3 eEvents = 7;
repeated internalMessage4 qEvents = 8;

// aux messages
repeated auxMessages auxEvents = 20;
```

}

This proto indicates that the only required fields are 1 and 2 (timestamp and strid, respectively). Decoding the wire format of the data as seen in the hexdump you can clearly see both required fields are present. Also, you can see that the repeated fields are missing (so its not like i'm missing a required field inside one of those!).

Any idea why protobufs is being a jerk here?

thanks!

tjac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that protobufs does not take kindly to being used across multiple threads using a globally declared variable. The error I am having is the result of me having multiple data streams which my server is processing. I am declaring the protobuf handler code above as a stand alone function which each thread calls. Since there is no exclusivity checking, as I'm in the middle of one call (the ParseFromArray, for instance), another call from another thread could be modifying the data within the object.

So long story short, I did not pay attention to the basic tenants of multithreaded programming and as a result I was dooming myself to spending a few hours trying to figure out how protobufs was failing. I can only hope this helps someone else in the future.